# Windows Phone 8 creating Calendar Application

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8, calendar

I am new to creating Windows Phone 8 application. I want to create a Calendar application that tracks my daily activity. I know there is already a build in Calendar application but I want to try to create my self in my own User Interface.

Is there a way to get the date of the calendar. For example, a build in API to access the date where I don't have to create it my self such as create a whole new calendar application in my own function. I will have to think of the leap year and also which month has 31 days and which doesn't. I did some research but most I get was to be able to access appointments from the build in Calendar. If there is anything wrong regarding my theory do correct me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I will have to think of the leap year and also which month has 31 days and which doesn't.

You shouldn't need to write any code for yourself which does that. You can either use the existing `DateTime` type, or potentially use my [Noda Time library](http://nodatime.org) which separates out the various "kinds" of date and time values you might have into different types. Either way, there are methods which already understand month lengths etc - you should make sure that you don't reinvent the wheel. Instead, think about what your data model looks like, what the user interactions are, what the presentation should look like etc. (One thing to think about *really early* is what you want to do about time zones.)

I would personally suggest *not* trying to integrate with the existing calendar, at least to start with. The more code you integrate with, the harder it's going to be. It really depends on how much this app is aimed at creating a full real solution, and how much it's a learning process.

Comment: Ill take your answer into consideration as I am not so sure how to use the libraries. I will also look on the points where you stated
(One thing to think about really early is what you want to do about time zones.) I will start finding a way on what the user interaction be too. Thanks so much for the answer!